# RethinkDB, add elements to an array that's nested

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

Using the example [here](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/update/), I've only added one more level to `notes`, it's mapped to an object whose elements themselves hold arrays

```
{
    id: 10001,
    name: "Bob Smith",
    notes: {
        alpha:['note1','note2','note3'],
        beta:['note1','note2','note3']
    }
}
```

Cannot for the life of me figure out how to append elements to `alpha` and `beta` however. I've tried variations of this:

```
update({ 
    notes:{  
        alpha: r.row("alpha").append('note4')  
    } 
})
```

but am not really getting anywhere.
Any help would be much appreciated~

Oh and the error message was `No attribute 'alpha' in object:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
r.db('test')
 .table('user')
 .get('10001')
 .update({
   notes: {
     alpha: r.row('notes')('alpha').append('note4'),
     beta: r.row('notes')('beta').append('note4')
   }
 }).run();
```

Comment: @House3272 Yeah :) It's easy to forget that you have to include the entire path (`('notes')('alpha')`) and not just the field you want to update (`('alpha')`). No problem!